# Sorting dictionaries elements by its numbers in descending order

Tags: python

```
Dict = {'Mango' : ['Green',59], 'Straberry': ['Red',33], 'Melon': ['Yellow',90] }
Dict = {'Melon': ['Yellow',90], 'Mango' : ['Green',59], 'Straberry': ['Red',33] }
```

How to descending sort dictionaries element by descending order as shown above Melon-Mango_straberry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to sort by number descending

```
dd = {'Mango' : ['Green',59], 'Straberry': ['Red',33], 'Melon': ['Yellow',90] }

ds = {v[0]:v[1] for v in sorted(dd.items(), key=lambda x: -x[1][1])}

print(ds)
```

Output

```
{'Melon': ['Yellow', 90], 'Mango': ['Green', 59], 'Straberry': ['Red', 33]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know that conceptualy, dict is a hash table and it should carry no particular order. That is true up to Python 3.6

However, Python 3.6 introduced the additional feature to its `dict` that retains the insertion order or the keys. Therefore, when you `print(your_dict)` you will see exactly the order you created the keys in `your_dict`.

With this feature, you can do this:

```
>>> Dict = {'Mango' : ['Green',59], 'Straberry': ['Red',33], 'Melon': ['Yellow',90] }
>>> Dict
{'Mango': ['Green', 59], 'Straberry': ['Red', 33], 'Melon': ['Yellow', 90]}
>>> Sorted = {k:Dict[k] for k in sorted(Dict.keys())}
>>> Sorted
{'Mango': ['Green', 59], 'Melon': ['Yellow', 90], 'Straberry': ['Red', 33]}
```

Comment: Yes, I looked at this type of code but I want to sort by 2nd element means the number of fruits, as I mentioned in my question Melon came first because it has 90 quantity.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer-

```py
Dict = sorted(Dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1], reverse=True)
```

Output

```
[('Melon', ['Yellow', 90]),
 ('Mango', ['Green', 59]),
 ('Straberry', ['Red', 33])]
```